# Does this query give me the active users for the final date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm going to use the following query to loop over multiple times to get active users for each day for the past few months. My question is: does this give me the active users for `20170130` or just distinct users or do these equate?

```
 WITH allTables as (
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id) as users
  FROM `com_sidearm_fanapp_uiowa_IOS.app_events_*`
  WHERE 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170130'
) SELECT users FROM allTables
```

In order to get active users for another day can I simply update `20170130` to a new date and `20170101` to a date 30 days back to get a new set of active users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your count will include any users that are in the table between the two dates, assuming their condition for being in the table is some sort of date field that you are referencing in the filter (if I'm mistaken please clarify in comments). So the answer to "Does this query give me the active users for the final date?" is yes, they will be included between start and end dates.

In order to get active users for another period of time, updating the dates in the filter will allow you to select distinct members that meet the criteria of being between the start and end dates.

Comment: Does between also use those two dates or only what's in between them?

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive of the start and end.

Comment: More usefully, you could have just looked it up in the google documentation, or tried it and saw what happened (said documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#comparison-operators)